# Enumerable invoke custom method

Tags: prototypejs

In PrototypeJS, the invoke method works nicely with an enumeration like,

```
$$('.mytags').invoke('setStyle',{fontWeight:bold})
```

I'm having trouble making this work against my own custom methods.  What is the trick?
Let say I have:

```
function myMethod(element) {
  element.insert('bingo');
}
```

If I try,

```
$$('.mytags').invoke('myMethod');
```

The code fails:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`myMethod()` needs to be a method on the prototype of the items in the array.

for instance `setStyle()` is the method `$('id').setStyle()`

to accomplish what you are trying to do you need to define your method first and then add it to the prototype of the items you are trying to iterate over.

If the items are Elements then you should be able to use `Element.addMethods()`

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/addMethods/

to add the methods to the tags you want or add to all elements.